# How to include multiple conditions in afterEQ in rome js calendar?

Tags: javascript, calendar

In [Rome](http://bevacqua.github.io/rome/), I would like to include multiple conditions, in my second calendar, that it would disallow dates that are earlier than today AND disallow dates that are earlier than what was chosen in first calendar.

```
var today = moment().format();

var startDate = rome(startDateElem, {dateValidator : rome.val.afterEq(today)});
var endDate = rome(endDateElem, {dateValidator : rome.val.afterEq([startDateElem, 
today])});
```

I could specify default value to start date (today), but is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should be like this:

```
var moment = rome.moment;
var today = moment().format();

var startDate = rome(startDateElem, {dateValidator : rome.val.afterEq(today)});
var endDate =rome(endDateElem, {dateValidator:function(d){
   var m = moment(d);
  var startD=rome(startDateElem).getDate();
  if(startD){     
    return m.isAfter(today)&& m.isAfter(startD);
  }else{
    return m.isAfter(today)
  }   }
});
```

this a [working demo](http://codepen.io/aitnasser/pen/pgwVxy) that can help you

Comment: that is not doing what i would like it to do, this lets me choose dates on endDate calendar before today, which is not what i want

Comment: @SiimKallari i have updated the code and now it work fine